# Getting reddit API before and after parameters in JSON response

Tags: php, json, api, reddit

I'm making call in PHP, with the following syntax:

```
<?php
$subreddit = 'cats';
$limit = 15;
$source = "https://www.reddit.com/r/$subreddit.json?limit=$limit";
$json = file_get_contents($source);
$js = json_decode($json);


foreach($js->data as $n) {          
    var_dump($js);      
} // endforeach
?>
```

Works as expected, and returns something like this:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'kind' => string 'Listing' (length=7)
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'modhash' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=15)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[3]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[23]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[39]
              ...
          3 ...
              ...
      public 'after' => string 't3_3guzfa' (length=9)
      public 'before' => null
```

Then I try to define the after variable inside the loop, and the loop becomes

```
foreach($js->data as $n) {

    var_dump($js); 

    $after = $n->data->after;
    echo ("This:" . $after);

} // endforeach
```

Which results, as you suspect, into "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\var_launchers\A1\build\index-return.php on line 13"

How do I get to that "after" value? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. So this code

`foreach($js->data as $n) {
   
 var_dump($js); 
  
 $after = $n->after;
 echo ("This:" . $after);
} // endforeach`

returns: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\var\_launchers\A1\build\index-return.php on line 13" which is the line in which I'm trying to define $after. (i.e. $after = $n->after;)